# Как с помощью Interop Word вставить разрыв страницы?

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

У меня есть шаблон документа (docx), с маркерами, которые я заменяю текстом.

Пример:
.....

[FirstName]

[Salary]

[Age] и т.д.

И есть маркер [PageBreak], на месте которого должен быть разрыв страницы, т.е. все что ниже в шаблоне, должно быть уже на следующей странице.

Не пойму как это сделать.

Пробовал так:

```
range.InsertBreak(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdBreakType.wdSectionBreakOddPage);
```

Но на этом месте [PageBreak] просто добавлялась пустая строка, как \n\r.

Comment: 1. Записать в Word'е макрос. 2. Посмотреть его код. 3. Сделать так же.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пробуй так.

```
range.InsertBreak(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdBreakType.wdPageBreak);
```

Comment: Да, я так и делаю. Но потом я `_documentSource.ExportAsFixedFormat(fileName, WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);` - сохраняю в pdf. И эти разрывы не учитываются, вместо новой страницы просто пустая линия. Как если в word выбрать вид документа "Веб-документ".

Comment: @endovitskiiy вот конвертацию в PDF я к сожалению не разу не юзал так что не подскажу. Но мне кажется когда конвертирует он вмещает всё в одну страницу

Comment: @endovitskiiy, при экспорте указывайте параметр `includeDocProps: true`